# Mathematical expectation of $F_\xi(\xi)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider $F$ as a distribution function of some random variable $\xi$. The problem I'm trying to solve is to find integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(x)dF(x)
$$
From what I see, there are two ways of solving this problem.

**The first:**
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(x)dF(x)=\mathbb{E}F(\xi)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{P}(\xi<\xi)=\mathbb{P}(\xi<\xi)=\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)=0$

**The second:**
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(x)dF(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dF^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dG(x)=\frac{1}{2}.$
Where $G(x)=F(x)F(x)$ is a distribution function of some variable (not descending, $G(-\infty)=0, G(+\infty)=1$).

As for me the second answer is more satisfying. Because it's intuitively understandable ($\int x dx=\frac{x^2}{2} +C$) and probably can be proved strictly. 
But what's wrong with the first way? All I can think about is that if we define $F(x)=\mathbb{P}(\xi\leq x)$ so that it was left-continuous, then $\mathbb{E}F(\xi)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{P}(\xi\leq\xi)=\mathbb{P}(\xi=\xi)=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$. And the $0.5$ is in some way the mean of $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Mmh, we have $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(x)\text{d}F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(x)F'(x)\text{d}x=\left[\frac{1}{2}F^{2}(x)\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The faulty step is to believe that $E(F(\xi))$ is $P(\xi<\xi)$ (or $P(\xi\leqslant\xi)$, for that matter). Actually, $F(x)=P(\xi'\leqslant x)$ where $\xi'$ is an independent copy of $\xi$ hence $E(F(\xi))=P(\xi'\leqslant\xi)$, and this is indeed $\frac12$ when the distribution of $\xi$ has no atom. When there are atoms, $E(F(\xi))=\frac12(1+z)$ where $z$ is the sum of the squares of the masses of the atoms.

Comment: @Did
Thank you for your guidance! That was faulty indeed. Much appreciated. 
BTW, with atoms in distribution: $P(\xi' \leq \xi)=P(\xi \leq \xi')$ hence $P(\xi' \leq \xi)=\frac{1}{2}(1+P(\xi'=\xi))=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sum_iP(\xi = x_i, \xi' = x_i))=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sum_iP^2(\xi = x_i))$ since $\xi'$ and $\xi$ are independent. But if $F(x)=P(\xi < x)$, then $EF(\xi)=P(\xi'<\xi)=\frac{1}{2}(1-z)$ where $z$ is the sum of the squares of masses of the atoms.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I specified the CDF I was considering. Note that the other choice (that is, $F(x)=P(\xi<x)$) is becoming rather rare these days.